# Stream file into python-pptx with Dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash, python-pptx

I would like a Dash dashboard to extract data from powerpoint .pptx files, a deployment constraint is that we can't read or write files to a directory so I would like to stream the input file straight into python-pptx's Presentation function.

here is a small reprex:

```
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from pptx import Presentation

server = Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(server=server)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H1("File Browser"),
        html.H2("Upload"),
        dcc.Upload(
            id="upload-data",
            children=html.Div(
                ["Drag and drop or click to select a file to upload."]
            ),
           multiple=True,
        ),
        html.H2("Shape List"),
        html.Ul(id="shape-list"),
    ],
    style={"max-width": "500px"},
)


@app.callback(
    Output("shape-list", "children"),
    [Input("upload-data", "filename"), Input("upload-data", "contents")],
)
def update_output(uploaded_filenames, uploaded_file_contents):
    shape_text = []
    if uploaded_filenames is not None and uploaded_file_contents is not None:
        for name, data in zip(uploaded_filenames, uploaded_file_contents):
            prs = Presentation(data)
            shape_text += [shape.text for shape in prs.slides[0].shapes]
    
    return [html.Li(txt) for txt in shape_text]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8888)
```

which gives error:

```
pptx.exc.PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at 'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation;base64...
```

I tried a few different attempts at encoding/decoding the input with StringIO and BytesIO but couldn't get it into a working format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` property contains also content type, which should be separated before doing the base64 decoding. Hence the parsing code should be along the lines of,

```
content_type, content_string = data.split(',')
prs = Presentation(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(content_string)))
```

Replacing

```
prs = Presentation(data)
```

in you example with that parsing code,  I am able to parse a pptx file as intended.